# Understanding 「いたずらもここまで手が込んでくると まあまあかな」

Tags: meaning, translation

From the first episode of *Death Note*, the main character ponders some crazy claims made in a notebook he finds. He eventually mutters to himself:

> いたずらもここまで手が込んでくると まあまあかな

Literally speaking, this seems to mean something like:

> As for whether this is also a prank, if up to here it's complicated, then "my, my".

But I'm pretty sure I'm not parsing right because it doesn't seem to quite make any sense. Is there a better way to translate this sentence (while keeping the Japanese translation as literal/close to the Japanese as possible)?

Ultimately, I'm assuming the sentence translates to something like:

> If, up to here, this has just all been a complicated prank, then ... "my, my".

But I don't see how the sentence is quite conveying this, grammatically. (And as I side note I don't understand why も is being used after いたずら, instead of は).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several key issues here which I thought were interesting and may not be straightforward. I will give you a breakdown.

- も

"even" I feel this も stresses the topic.

いたずらも: Even as a prank

- くる

As @aguijonazo points out this くる is defined as ([デジタル大辞泉（小学館）](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B/)):

> ９ （補助動詞）動詞の連用形に接続助詞「て」が付いた形に付く。
>
> ㋐少しずつ移行したり、程度が進んだりして、しだいにその状態になる。だんだん…になる。「日増しに暖かくなってきた」「最近太ってきた」

- 手が込んでくる

Therefore, here this phrase means "intricately/elaborately crafted/devised"

- と

I would think of this と as "when" rather than "if".

- まあまあ

means "not too bad"

Thus

> いたずらもここまで手が込んでくるとまあまあかな

means:

> (Even) as a prank, it is not bad when they put so much effort into it

Comment: This explanation is very good but I see this くる more in the neutral (i.e. not negative) sense of 事態が進行してある段階に至る as スーパー大辞林 on my phone puts it.

Comment: I would have felt the sense of the speaker being affected by something negative if the verb were for something the prankster deliberately did such as ここまで手をかけてくると.

Comment: @aguijonazo Hmm, I see. Let me chew it over a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The structure is

> いたずらもまあまあかな

where the following conditional is inserted

> ここまで手が込んでくると.

The former means

> Prank is okay as well.

and the latter

> if (it is) contrived this much.

You should be able to see the meaning simply by combining these.

---

BTW [Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/My%2C+my) does seem to say *my, my* is まあまあ, but I suppose it is in the sense of emphatic まあ (Wow). which seems consistent with ["*interjection* An expression of surprise, incredulity, or pleasure."](https://www.zurich.co.jp/car/useful/guide/cc-roadsign-list-meaning/?utm_medium=pas&utm_source=iya&utm_campaign=tx&utm_content=100046&argument=hT7qcPFB&dmai=pas_iya_tx_100046&yclid=YSS.1001033242.EAIaIQobChMIgM6c7arj-gIV1cEWBR3Ggg7CEAAYAiAAEgKqmPD_BwE)

The まあまあ here is *so-so* ([#3](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%82%E3%81%BE%E3%81%82/#je-71177))